# How to solve SDE with Ito formula?

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

thank you very much for clicking on my question.
I'm working on this paper (https://www.duo.uio.no/bitstream/handle/10852/10566/pm12-05.pdf?sequence=1) (Page 3) and want to solve the following SDE:

$dT(t)=db(t)-a(t)(T(t)-b(t))dt+\sigma(t)dB(t)$

The solotion is:
$T(t)=b(t)+(T(0)-b(0))e^{-\int_{0}^{t} a(s)ds}+e^{-\int_{0}^{t} a(s)ds} \int_{0}^{t} \sigma(u)e^{\int_{0}^{u} a(s)ds} dB(u)$

In my case a(t) and b(t) are deterministic functions and B(t) the standard brownian motion.
It is described that the SDE is solved using the Ito formula.

My question is why I can use the ito formula at all since the SDE has to represent the following form: $dT(t)=a(t,T(t))dt+b(t,T())dB(t)$? Or how do I have to deal with $db(t)$?

The second question is how to solve the SDE with Ito? with $Y(t)=T(t)e^{\int_{0}^{u} a(s)ds}$?

As an exercise, I solved the ornstein-Uhlenbeck SDE with ito:

$dX_t=\theta (\mu-X_t)dt+ \sigma dW_t$
with $Y_t=X_t e^{\theta t}$

Thank you very much

Comment: This *is* an OU-SDE: \begin{align}
T(t)&=T(0)+b(t)-b(0)-\int_0^ta(s)\Big(T(s)-b(s)\Big)\,ds+\int_0^t\sigma(s)\,dB(t)\\
&=T(0)-\int_0^ta(s)\Big(T(s)-b(s)\Big)-b'(s)\,ds+\int_0^t\sigma(s)\,dB(t)\\
&=T(0)-\int_0^ta(s)\Big(T(s)-\color{red}{c(s)}\Big)\,ds+\int_0^t\sigma(s)\,dB(t)\,.
\end{align} Just figure out what $\color{red}{c(s)}$ is.

Comment: @KurtG. thanks for your response! By calculation $c(s)=b(s)+\frac{b^{\prime}(s)}{a(s)}$. But that's probably not what you meant. A further explanation would help me a lot

Comment: That's what I meant.

Comment: @KurtG. I see :) so i can convert my initial SDE to $dT(t)=-a(t)(T(t)-b(t)-\frac{b^{\prime}(t)}{a(t)})dt+\sigma(t)dB(t)$ and then use ito with $Y(t)=T(t)e^{-\int_{0}^{t} a(s)ds}$?!

Comment: You could. I just noticed that you spelled out the solution already in OP. So why came that question in the first place? A probably even simpler approach is to write the SDE for $S:=T-b\,.$ Can you proceed?

Comment: The paper is about weather derivatives and I would like to understand it in detail. So my first approach is to use ito with the new SDE and $Y(t)=T(t)e^{\int_{0}^{t} a(s)ds}$. So we have according to ito formula:  
  $dY(t)=(a(t)T(t)e^{\int_{0}^{t} a(s)ds}-a(t)(T(t)-b(t)-\frac{b^{\prime}(t)}{a(t)})e^{\int_{0}^{t} a(s)ds})dt+\sigma(t)e^{\int_{0}^{t} a(s)ds}dB(t)$
 $=e^{\int_{0}^{t} a(s)ds}(a(t)b(t)-b^{\prime}(t))dt+\sigma(t)e^{\int_{0}^{t} a(s)ds}dB(t)$

Comment: and then  $T(t)e^{\int_{0}^{t} a(s)ds}=T(0)+\int_{0}^{t}e^{\int_{0}^{u} a(s)ds}(a(u)b(u)-b^{\prime}(u))dt+\int_{0}^{t}\sigma(u)e^{\int_{0}^{u} a(s)ds}dB(u)$ but how to calculate the "dt" integral? Is there a way to solve this or should I try your idea with $S:=T-b$? Thanks for the help!

Comment: If -as you say- you solved the OU-SDE with Ito you must be able to solve (the OU-SDE)
$$
dS_t=-a\,S_t\,dt+\sigma\,dB_t\,,\quad (a,b\text{ depend on }t)\,.
$$
Then $T=S+b$ *obviously* solves your original SDE:
$$
dT_t-db=-a(T_t-b)\,dt+\sigma\,B_t\,.
$$ My initial comment seems to lead to some overthinking.

Comment: I think thats it. From $S_t:=T_t-b_t$ we get the SDE $dS_t=-a_tS_tdt+\sigma_tdB_t$. Then bei Ito's formula we have $dS_te^{\int_{0}^{t} a(s)ds}=e^{\int_{0}^{t} a(s)ds}\sigma_tdB_t$ and so $S_t=e^{-\int_{0}^{t} a(s)ds}(T_0-b_0)+e^{-\int_{0}^{t} a(s)ds}\int_{0}^{t}\sigma_te^{\int_{0}^{u} a(s)ds}dB_u$. SInce $S_t:=T_t-b_t$ we have the solution?!

Comment: Why that question mark? I want you to be *sure* not ask me for confirmation. Sloppy notation: $d\color{red}(S_te^{\int_0^t a(s)\,ds}\color{red})=e^{\int_0^t a(s)\,ds}\sigma_t\,dB_t\,.$

Comment: Haha, after I have slept on it for a night I am sure:) Thank you very much for your help!